# AWS Java S3-Upload Error while Runing Applet in HTML

Tags: applet, amazon-s3

I solved the problem upto certain extent by using the following command

```
$applettviewer -J-Djava.security.policy=java.policy.applet MyApplet.html
```

it does not show any error like before.
I came to know that my Applet has to be signed even im running in my Local System.

This is my test.html

```
File Name : test.HTML
<html>
<applet code="*MyApplet.class*"  archive="aws-java-sdk-1.2.12.jar,commons-codec-1.3.jar,commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,httpclient-4.1.1.jar,httpcore-4.1.jar,jackson-core-asl-1.4.3.jar,mail-1.4.3.jar,stax-1.2.0.jar,stax-api-1.0.1.jar" width="500" height="500"></applet>
</html>
```

my Folder structure is as follows:

```
bin/ 
|----------------- MyApplet.class
|----------------- AwsCredentials.properties
|----------------- mime.types
|----------------- required Jar Files
|----------------- java.policy.applet
|----------------- test.html ( HTML file to Load the Applet)
```

I dont know how to sign the Class file.
Please guide me.

Regards,
Ananthavel

Answer (score 1):

> I dont know how to sign the Class file.

See [Steps for the Code Signer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/signer.html) in the Java tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your project as jar file. Then using keytool and jarsigner located in bin folder of jdk you need to sign your applet
and change your html as

```
<applet code="MyApplet.class"  archive="MyApplet.jar,aws-java-sdk-1.2.12.jar,commons-codec-1.3.jar,commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,httpclient-4.1.1.jar,httpcore-4.1.jar,jackson-core-asl-1.4.3.jar,mail-1.4.3.jar,stax-1.2.0.jar,stax-api-1.0.1.jar" width="500" height="500"></applet>
```